# How to return object directly with module exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why cat class cant set property, whereas module exports is new object that i pass.

> TypeError: Cannot set property '#sound' of undefined

animal class

```
class Animal
{
    #sound;
    
    // i make it return object this object class.
    setSound(sound)
    {
        this.#sound = sound;

        return this;
    }

    getSound()
    {
        return this.#sound;
    }
}

// i make it create object and return that object.
module.exports = new Animal;
```

cat class

```
const {setSound} = require('./animal');

const cat = setSound('Meow');

console.log(cat.getSound());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, `this` simply refers to whatever comes before the `.`. For example:

```
 function t() {
     return this;
 }

 a = {t: t}
 a.t()
 // returns a
```

If you call `t` directly you get undefined:

```
 t()
 // undefined
```

So in your case you are calling the method directly without a `.`, so this will be undefined.

You can fix it in two ways, one is fixing your import:

```
const cat = require('./animal');
cat.setSound('Meow') // This works because there is a period
```

Or using bind:

```
class Animal {
    constructor() {
         this.setSound = this.setSound.bind(this);
         this.getSound = this.getSound.bind(this);
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

This basically "freezes" the value of this and prevents it from changing if the method is ever disconnected from the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You export an instance of class so you can not just import the method from it. Do something like:

```
const CAT = require('./animal');

const cat = CAT.setSound('Meow');

console.log(cat.getSound());
```